# Alternative definition on parallel lines

Tags: terminology, definition, hyperbolic-geometry

I was puzzling about an alternative definition of a parallel line . 
With parallel lines is I mean  converging (horo) parallel line .

I wanted a definition that did not mention ideal points or lines intersecting at the absolute or anything like that.

And after some puzzling I came to the following idea:

The two lines a and b are horoparallel if and only if for every point A on a, if C is the point on b nearest to A then there is a point D on a that is nearer to C than A.

Is this a  definition correct or did I overlook something?

Comment: Do two such parallel lines  make same angle to a non-parallel  cutting line ?

Comment: How is this question appreciably different from your recent ["Good way to describe 'converging parallel lines'?"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1924831/409)?

Comment: @Blue this is more a possible answer to that question of my

Answer (score 0):

The definition of parallel lines in hyperbolic geometry is that $l$ and $m$ are parallel if they do not intersect and further for each point $P$ on $l$ any line though $P$ lying between $l$ and $m$ will intersect $m$.

Comment: What does horoparallel mean ? I think is also called parallel, or is there another notion ?

Comment: horoparallel  = limiting parallel  (sometimes called critically parallel, horoparallel or just parallel) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limiting_parallel , the bit "any line though P lying between l and m will intersect m." is unclear what do you mean by it?